# Wazuh log error after run wazuh-passwords-tools.sh

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, wazuh

The script I ran successfully on my healthy and previously used Wazuh installation:

```
usr/share/wazuh-indexer/plugins/opensearch-security/tools/wazuh-passwords-tool.sh --change-all
```

Afterwards, it provided the following output (with example passwords, of course):

```
INFO: Wazuh API admin credentials not provided, Wazuh API passwords not changed.
INFO: The password for user admin is wcAny.XUwOVWHFy.+7tW9l8gUW1L8N3j
INFO: The password for user kibanaserver is qy6fBrNOI4fD9yR9.Oj03?pihN6Ejfpp
INFO: The password for user kibanaro is Nj*sSXSxwntrx3O7m8ehrgdHkxCc0dna
INFO: The password for user logstash is nQg1Qw0nIQFZXUJc8r8+zHVrkelch33h
INFO: The password for user readall is s0iWAei?RXObSDdibBfzSgXdhZCD9kH4
INFO: The password for user snapshotrestore is Mb2EHw8SIc1d.oz.nM?dHiPBGk7s?UZB
WARNING: Wazuh indexer passwords changed. Remember to update the password in the Wazuh dashboard and Filebeat nodes if necessary, and restart the services.
```

My dashboard password changed when trying to log in, but now it's not collecting logs. How can I identify the issue? I think I may have entered some passwords incorrectly.